# Apply Motion Tween to many frames?

Tags: flash, tween

I hav created 24 frames (i use 24fps) by hand depicting a small move ...

Now I need to repeat this move for 1 minute and move it from left to right
through the screen ... is there a way to avoid copying-pasting
these 24 frames and chaning them a little to the others 59 seconds
by using motion tween?

So, iam looking for a way to combine both the 24 frames and apply motion tween
to them.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Make the move into an Actor, and then move the Actor across the area you need.

It has been a while since I use flash, tho.

Comment: hi! thanks for answering. i searched a little about actors but don't find anything. i don't know what it is.. could you support me with a link maybe on how to use is, what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its' actually very easy to do. You make a container movieclip, copy the frames into it and then you just motion tween that container. Simple, no? :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to copy the 24 frames to cover the remaining 59 seconds, instead, create a movie clip, and put the 24 frames inside it, then place the 24 frame movieclip on stage.

Then you can tween the movieclip you created as you like for the time you need, you will have the 24 frame animation moving as you tween the created movieclip.

I hope this will help you :-)